# What could happen if I touch a constant current source for example 5 Volts 1 Amp..?

Tags: power-supply, current-source

Yes, I am talking about a constant current source not a voltage source. Would the 1 Amp go to my body?

Comment: if the constant current source is able to ramp up the voltage until 1 A flows through you, then yes

Comment: This also gives relevant information: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/487891/152903

Answer (score 4):

If you touch a 1 amp constant current source with a maximum voltage of 5v, then the very large impedance of your body will max out the voltage of the source, resulting in 5v and essentially no current flow.

Comment: so basically a 5 volts 1 Amp is safe?

Comment: @Rocket I would touch a 1A current source capable of outputting a maximum of 5V before I would poke my finger with a pointy wodden toothpick.

Answer (score 2):

Under these conditions (extremely high load resistance), your *1 A constant current source* will behave as a *5 V constant voltage source*.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum power it can output is \$5W\$.
Human body's resistance varies between \$1k\$ to \$100k\$;so the \$1A\$ current source fails doing it's job and pumps only \$50 \mu A\$ to \$5 mA\$ through your body.

Answer (score 0):

At low frequencies (DC) nothing would happen as the compliance of the source is too low and the body impedance is too high,thus very little current would flow.  But, if this is RF you could get a nasty burn or sever electrical shock.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. It is unlikely that the OP (original poster) will understand what 'RF' stands for. Hit the edit link below your question ...